# Kendo UI grid template column

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have this grid in my page and it works great :

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<SalaryAdmin.Classes.ReturnedCompareHoghough>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .EnableCustomBinding(true)
    .BindTo(Model.Comparehoghough)
    .Columns(columns => {
        columns.Template(@<text><input type="text" name="@item.MelliCode" class="sel" /></text>).Width(50);

        columns.Bound(o => o.MomayezFinalTax).Format("{0:n0}").Title("مالیات قابل پرداخت پس از اعمال معافیت موضوع ماده 92 (ویژه مناطق کمتر توسعه یافته) نظر ممیز");
        columns.Bound(o => o.FinalTax).Format("{0:n0}").Title("مالیات قابل پرداخت پس از اعمال معافیت موضوع ماده 92 (ویژه مناطق کمتر توسعه یافته)");

    })
    .Pageable()
    .Navigatable()        
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Server().Total((int)ViewData["totalMoadi"]))
)
```

I replace that grid with this version :

```
   @(Html.Kendo().Grid<SalaryAdmin.Classes.ReturnedCompareHoghough>()
                    .Name("Grid").EnableCustomBinding(true).BindTo(Model.Comparehoghough)

    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Template(@<text><input type="text" name="@item.MelliCode" class="sel" /></text>).Width(50);

        columns.Bound(o => o.MomayezFinalTax).Format("{0:n0}").Title("مالیات قابل پرداخت پس از اعمال معافیت موضوع ماده 92 (ویژه مناطق کمتر توسعه یافته) نظر ممیز").Width(200).ClientFooterTemplate("#=sum#");
        columns.Bound(o => o.FinalTax).Format("{0:n0}").Title("مالیات قابل پرداخت پس از اعمال معافیت موضوع ماده 92 (ویژه مناطق کمتر توسعه یافته)").Width(200).ClientFooterTemplate("#=sum#");
    })
    .Pageable()
   .Scrollable(scr => scr.Height(420))
                     .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax().Aggregates(
                         ag =>
                         {
                             ag.Add(h => h.MomayezFinalTax).Sum();
                             ag.Add(h => h.FinalTax).Sum();
                         }
                         ).Read(read => read.Action("ChangeHoghough_Read", "list", new { id = Model.list.GuidList })))
)
```

it works great too except textbox is not displayed. is it possible to display text in seond version? If yes, How can I get entered value in postback? I tried to get in paging event but in paging event a linq code is posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming the point of the different grids is to move from Server binding to Ajax binding.
The text box isn't displayed because you are using the Server Template instead of the client side template. Try this for the column:

```
columns.ClientTemplate("#: <input type='text' name='MelliCode' class='sel' /> #")...
```

The syntax is a bit different, here's an [overview](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/framework/templates/overview).
I'm not sure but the BindTo Parameter might mean that you are getting the data twice on initial load.

Comment: I want to get value that entered by user in textbox. How can  do this?

Comment: Did you want to get the value client side or sever side? If server side, how are you posting back to the server? Your code only shows a grid...

Comment: I want to get it server side. i want to change MomayezFinalTax field according to value that user entered.

Comment: I want to get it server side. i want to change MomayezFinalTax field according to value that user entered. I putted a button that posted back to the controller but datarequest was null or didn't contain grid data.

Comment: I would need to see the code with the button in it to be able to help. If you start a new question with the new code you mentioned, I will take a look at it. Until then, this might help: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing-inline

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this.

```
columns.Template(c => "<input type='text' name='AdminEmail' value='"+  c.Email +"'> ").Title("").Width(140).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center; white-space: nowrap; text-decoration: underline;" }).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center; white-space: nowrap;" });
```